# Basel problem using $f(x)=x$ on $[0,2\pi)$

Tags: real-analysis, parsevals-identity

So I need to verify

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

Using Parsevals identity on $f(x)=x$ on $[0,2\pi)$. Does this mean if $a_n$ are the Fourier coefficients then

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \vert a_n \vert^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} x^2 dx.$$

Where

$$a_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(x) e^{-inx}dx.$$

But this becomes just $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} xe^{-inx}dx.$ which I computed using IBP to being $-\frac{1}{in}$. (Though this is not the answer on integral calculators). Then do I take the absolute value of $-\frac{1}{in}$ and square it to get $\frac{1}{n^2}$ which has value $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}x^2dx$ but this becomes $\frac{2 \pi^2}{3}$. Where Am I going wrong?? Can someone please help me see why I don’t get the desired result ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4861181/use-the-result-and-parsevals-identity-to-compute-the-value-of-sum-n-1-in/4861196#4861196 I have answered a similar question recently: Maybe this helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be comparing the sum over the integers directly with the sum over the natural numbers. You need to first calculate $a_0$ separately,

\begin{eqnarray*}
a_0
&=&
\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=&
\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}x\,\mathrm dx\\
&=&
\pi\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

and then actually perform the sum over the integers (using $|a_{-n}|=|a_n|$):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty|a_n|^2
&=&
|a_0|^2+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty|a_n|^2
\\
&=&
\pi^2+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Then using

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty|a_n|^2
&=&
\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}x^2\,\mathrm dx
\\
&=&
\frac {(2\pi)^2}3
\end{eqnarray*}

(you were missing either a factor of $2$ or a pair of parentheses there), you get

$$
\frac{(2\pi)^2}3=\pi^2+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}
$$

and thus

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6\;.
$$

Comment: didnt you mean a power of $3$ instead of $2$ for the $(2 \pi)^2$?

Comment: @anonymous: No, one power is divided out by the factor $\frac1{2\pi}$ in front.

Comment: youre right i missed that, thanks!